json serialization custom prototype
I am getting this response from vendor API and would like to serialize. However, the structure does not allow for direct serialization (at least not that I have sorted out) as this is an object name "a3_amt_ditx-refr-sa3x-tamtx"
This is the prototype. HVR/Fivetran is the vendor
job<str> *: {      'state' :      'num_retries' ?:      'log_job_err_tstamp' ?: <date_str_z>     'latency' ?: secs     'next_run' ?: <date_str_z> }
this the response
{ "a3_amt_ditx-refr-sa3x-tamtx": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "amt_a3_dev-activate": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "amt_a3_dev-cap-samtd": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "amt_a3_dev-integ-ta3d": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "amt_a3_ditx-activate": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "amt_a3_ditx-cap-samtx": { "state": "SUSPEND", "log_job_err_tstamp": "2024-04-10T19:09:15Z" }, "amt_a3_ditx-integ-ta3x": { "state": "SUSPEND", "log_job_err_tstamp": "2024-04-10T16:54:51Z" }, "amt_a3_ditx-refr-samtx-ta3x": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "azureinv-refr-sazureinv-tazureinv": { "state": "PENDING" }, "hvrstats": { "state": "RUNNING" }, "hvrtesting-activate": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "hvrtesting-cap-shvr": { "state": "SUSPEND", "log_job_err_tstamp": "2024-04-10T18:04:36Z" }, "hvrtesting-integ-thvr2": { "state": "SUSPEND" }, "hvrtesting-integ-thvr3": { "state": "SUSPEND" } } 
Looking to create a Jobs class in VB.net. Any help greatly appreciated.
not what i need
`Public Class AmtA3DitxActivate
Public Property state As String
End Class
Public Class AmtA3DitxCapSamtx
Public Property state As String
Public Property log_job_err_tstamp As DateTime
End Class
Public Class AmtA3DitxIntegTa3x
Public Property state As String
Public Property log_job_err_tstamp As DateTime
End Class
Public Class AmtA3DitxRefrSamtxTa3x
Public Property state As String
End Class`

I was able to sort this myself. thanks for reading if you did! raw conversion.
Dim jsonToDictionary As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(jobsJson)
